# How can I animate a static object in a WPF storyboard

Tags: xaml, singleton, storyboard, static-members

I have a WPF program to which I need to add a "Demo mode". Since I want my designers to be able to modify the demo mode without me having to recompile the program each time, I tough it would be a great idea to use a storyboard from an external XAML file. The "Demo mode" is basically a storyboard animating some of the application's dependency properties.

To expose my application's DPs, I have created a public static member (singleton) of the application's class so that the application's DPs are always available externally. In this case, the storyboard will be accessing them.

In the external XAML file, I have added the proper xmlns referencing correctly the application's namespace/assembly. So in theory, I should be able to access the application's DP in a Storyboard.

The problem is that I don't know how to animate a DP of a static object in a Storyboard when the object is not declared/named in the XAML. When declaring a storyboard animation frame, the only storyboard's attached property are *Storyboard.TargetName* and *Storyboard.TargetProperty*.

I would appreciate if someone could give me a hint to get me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this out, but if it is doable I would guess it looks something like this:

```
<Storyboard ..>
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.Target="{x:Static MyNS:MyClass.Singleton}" 
                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="MyProperty" .../>
</Storyboard>
```